# getting resources inside a built application

Tags: java

i want to get files inside a folder when my application is running, so i know that i need to get it as resouce, if i will get it as file, it wont work, so it what i did.

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Catalogo.class);
            jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("catalogos/");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream));
            String line;
            try {
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    InputStream resourceAsStream1 = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("catalogos/"+line);
                    tempCat = (Catalogo) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(resourceAsStream1);
                    if(tempCat != null){
                        codigoCurso = String.valueOf(tempCat.getCourse().getId());
                        nomeDoCurso = dados.get(codigoCurso);
                        anoCatalogo = String.valueOf(tempCat.getAno());
                        if(nomeDoCurso == null){
                            dados.put(codigoCurso, tempCat.getCourse().getNome());
                        }
                        anos.add(anoCatalogo);
                    }
                }
```

What i want to do is, get all files inside a folder (`/catalogos/`) and loop through and unmarshall each to an object so i will be able to access the property i need. So, when i run this with netbeans, works perfectly, but when i build and run the jar, i dont get the same result i've got using netbeans, i mean, the data is not where i expected.

Comment: You can open up the jar file using any program that handles zip files and inspect its contents to see the folder structure

Comment: @cricket_007 it has all the folders, including the one i want. In my project the folder was inside src/ and in the jar its on /

Comment: You may need to use a leading slash on the resource path, then

Comment: @cricket_007 nop. it throws a null pointer if i use `/catalogos/`

Comment: And what was the error before? File not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to get files from a directory in current runnable jar file and read these files contents.

Assume you have a NetBeans project with name "FolderTestApp". Do the following steps:

1. In your project root folder `FolderTestApp\` create folder `myFiles`.
2. Copy your `catalogos` folder to the `FolderTestApp\myFiles\`

[image: files in the project structure]

`myFiles` folder is necessary to preserve `catalogos` folder in your jar file structure when project jar is being generated. `myFiles` folder will disappear from jar file, but `catalogos` folder will remain.

[image: catalogos folder in generated jar file]

If you don't do these steps, and place `catalogos` directly to the project folder (not as a child folder for myFiles), then your files from catalogos folder will be placed to the root of your jar file.

3. Add `myFiles` folder as a source folder in netbeans project properties.

[image: adding folder to the source folders list]

Assume your property files contain the following contents:

file1.properties:

```
key11=value11
key12=value12
key13=value13
```

file2.properties:

```
key21=value21
key22=value22
key23=value23
```

**Please note**, that code below is not optimized. It is plain'n'dirty proof of concept to show, how to solve your task.

Add the following class to your project:

```
package folderapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;


public class FolderTestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        new FolderTestApp();
    }

    public FolderTestApp() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        // determining the running jar file location
        String jarFilePath = getClass().getProtectionDomain().
                                getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();

        // note, that the starting / is removed
        // because zip entries won't start with this symbol
        String zipEntryFolder = "catalogos/";

        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream
                = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(jarFilePath))) {

            ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            while (zipEntry != null) {

                System.out.println("processing: " + zipEntry.getName());

                if (zipEntry.getName().startsWith(zipEntryFolder)) {
                    // directory "catalogos" will appear as a zip-entry
                    // and we're checking this condition
                    if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                        // adding symbol / because it is required for getResourceAsStream() call
                        printProperties("/" + zipEntry.getName());
                    }

                }

                zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            }

        }

    }

    public void printProperties(String path) throws IOException {

        try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)) {
            InputStreamReader fr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(br);

            System.out.println("contents from: " + path + "\n");

            Set<Object> keySet = properties.keySet();
            for (Object key : keySet) {
                System.out.println(key + " = " + properties.get(key));
            }

            System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        }
    }

}
```

Set this class as the main class in your project settings (`Run` section).

[image: main class setup]

And build your project via menu: `Run - Build`.

As your project has been built, open `FolderTestApp/dist` folder, where your generated jar is located and run this jar file:

[image: running the generated jar file]

That's it :)

Comment: Your solution worked, i managed to create a code based on yours, but i will wait some other more efficienty answer. The amount of files in that folder can increase, and that wont be good scanning every single file inside the jar.

Comment: @GoldenMedal As far as I know, for standard classes there's no other way than process ZipEntries one after another. There's no way to get ZipEntries belonging to particular folder. Moreover ZipEntries are not files, they are _headers_ and iterating over zip entries you are not iterating over files, you are iterating over file header records. They are quite small and don't take noticeable time to process.

Comment: Rather than assuming the .jar is a physical file, you can simply leave the value of getLocation() as a URL, then use `new ZipInputStream(location.openStream())`.  This allows the code to work in distributed environments such as Web Start and applets.  Also, it should be noted that [ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource() can return null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource--), so this approach is not entirely reliable.